# Segmentation core dumped error while merging gray channels

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv. I am trying to merge 3 gray channels to form a color image. I have used 'merge' for this. But i am getting "Sgmentation fault (core dumped)" as error. My code is given below.'img' is the input image and fin_img is the output image.

```
 bimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
 gimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
 rimgFiltered.create(img.size(),CV_8UC1);
 fin_img.create(img.size(),CV_8UC3);
 merge(bimgFiltered,fin_img);
 merge(gimgFiltered,fin_img);
 merge(rimgFiltered,fin_img);
```

Comment: "Segmentation core"?! Are you just *guessing* random words you've heard elsewhere and hope that they become a meaningful question?

Comment: -1 for not reading the docs at all

Answer (score 1):

wrong usage of the [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) function.

instead of applying it 3 times, give it a vector or array:

```
Mat chan[] = {bimgFiltered,gimgFiltered,rimgFiltered};

merge(chan,3,fin_img);
```